# ssh reverse tunnel with remote ip

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

From a server 192.168.0.**1**, I'd like to reach a server 192.168.0.**2** on port 80.

192.168.0.**2** can reach 192.168.0.**1**, but 192.168.0.**1** can't reach 192.168.0.**2** (firewall).

I have set up a reverse proxy, by typing the following command on 192.168.0.**2**:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R0.0.0.0:80:localhost:80 192.168.0.1
```

now 192.168.0.**1** can reach 192.168.0.**2**, with the following command:

```
wget localhost:80
```

However I'd like to be able to reach 192.168.0.**2** by taping

```
wget 192.168.0.2:80
```

Is this possible, without messing with the DNS?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/661772/iptables-redirect-to-localhost

Comment: @7171u ok thanks, I have added a rule so that iptables -t nat -L shows: DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.2          tcp dpt:http to:127.0.0.1:80  however, the second wget is still not working, what could be wrong?

Comment: I have used this on RHEL7 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `GatewayPorts` in `sshd_config` otherwise the `*` or `0.0.0.0` will bind only to the loopback interface.

Also note that

> Privileged ports can be forwarded only when logging in as root on the remote machine.

From manual page for `ssh`:

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only.  This may be overridden by specifying a `bind_address`.  An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.  Specifying a remote `bind_address` will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

Comment: I have added the following line in /etc/ssh/sshd.config -> GatewayPorts clientspecified. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also I would try with `*` or address of outer interface (`192.168.0.1`) instead of `0.0.0.0` and I would watch for errors on both connections.

Comment: I tried both * and 192.168.0.1, to no success. I don't really know what errors to look for, the only thing I can tell you is that the tunnel itself works (wget localhost:80), as explained in the question, so the error is probably not coming from here. What doesn't work is just the wget 192.168.0.2:80, which is maybe an error with the iptables rule

Comment: Why do you try `wget 192.168.0.2:80`? You should try `wget 192.168.0.1:80`. This is where your port is forwarded, isn't it?

Comment: Well that's the whole point of my question. Say the server I would like to access is google.com, but I can't reach it directly, though google.com can reach me, I'd like to set up my network so that I can reach google.com transparently without having to change anything. So in the end of this configuration, I expect to be able to type wget google.com, not wget localhost or wget 192.168.0.1, which is my own ip.

Comment: If you don't see that IP addrees/host/you need to "fake" the DNS/hosts file somehow if you want to use still the real address. I don't know about any simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue on Ubuntu 14.04 (I tried both `GatewayPorts clientspecified` and `GatewayPorts yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

Instead, adding this to my `sshd_config` worked:

```
Match User !root
    GatewayPorts yes
```

That is, I had to specify a user to match the rule to.